# Creating XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have an XML file with the following format:

```
<information xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <fact>
    <header>some text</header>
    <text>some text</text>
  </fact>
<information>
```

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me creating an XML schema file alongside this? I currently have the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="information">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="fact">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

However when entered into a validator the following error appears:

Not valid.
Error - Line 12, 9: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'fact'. No child element is expected at this point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message points to line 12 in your input. The sample input shown has only 7 lines, so you must be validating a different instance.

My guess, based on no information at all, is that the `fact` element occurs more than once as a child of the `information` element.

If that's the case, then the schema needs to permit this: change `<xs:element name="fact">` to `<xs:element name="fact" maxOccurs="unbounded">`